# SQL Query needs to match similar records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a very large table of contacts which I am building an interface to help my client to de-dupe. Here is an example of the table content

```
id | firstname | lastname | email            | address1 | addres2 | verifiedAt |
1  | James     | johnson  | james@test.com   |          |         |            | 
2  | David     | bloggs   | james@bloggs.com |          |         |            |
3  | John      | nobel    | james@nobel.com  |          |         |            |
4  | Terry     | jacket   | james@jacket.com |          |         | 05/05/2013 |
5  | James     | johnson  | james@johnson.com|          |         |            |
6  | James     | privett  | james@test.com   |          |         |            |
```

I need to write a query that will return the first contact that has another contact in the same table where either the email addresses match or the firstname + lastname match.

Is this possible in a single query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works ([SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74c50/23)):

```
SELECT a.* FROM mytable a
JOIN (
    SELECT email
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY email
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) b ON a.email = b.email
UNION
SELECT a.* FROM mytable a
JOIN (
    SELECT firstname, lastname
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY firstname, lastname
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) b ON a.firstname = b.firstname AND a.lastname = b.lastname
```

To make sure that this query works fast, be sure to have at least following indexes:

```
 CREATE INDEX i1 ON mytable(email);
 CREATE INDEX i2 ON mytable(firstname, lastname);
```

Comment: The OP wants the first record for each duplicate, not all of them.

Comment: Uh, dang. Well, it is easy to wrap it into `SELECT TOP 1` then. However, I would think that if you want to get rid of dupes, you would rather see them all - otherwise it is difficult to say which one should be removed and which should stay.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74c50/46)).

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM
(      SELECT 
           MIN(id) as [id]
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY email
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT
          MIN(id) as [id]
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY firstName,lastName
        HAVING Count(*) > 1 )dups
JOIN myTable t
ON t.Id = dups.id
```

Answer (score 0):

One method:

```
with cte as 
(select c.*,
        row_number() over (partition by email order by id) rnem,
        count(*) over (partition by email) ctem,
        row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname order by id) rnfl,
        count(*) over (partition by firstname, lastname) ctfl
 from contacts c)
select * from cte
where (ctem > 1 and rnem = 1) or (ctfl > 1 and rnfl = 1)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b198b/2).